# Access view information from master page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a master page and would like to print out the view it is currently being used to render. For instance, someone types in /path/method into the browser. In my master page, I'd like to to print `<%= "path" %>` somewhere and `<%= "method" %>` somewhere.

How can I get access to this information from the master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like what I was looking for:

```
IView view = ((ViewPage)this.Page).ViewContext.View;
string viewname = ((WebFormView)view).ViewPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the controller of the view you are accessing:

```
ViewBag.ViewName = "MyViewName" or ViewData["ViewName"] = "MyViewName"
```

Then use it at the MasterPage

```
<%= ViewBag.ViewName %> or <%= ViewData["ViewName"] %>
```